# Find the first minimum value in R?

Tags: r

How can I find the first minimum value in a vector? E.g., in `y` I'd like to return `3` because it is the first time the values on either side of `y[3]` are greater than `y[3]`. I wrote a function to do this but wondering if there is an easier way? I also need to account for the case when the first value is less than the second value. E.g., in `z`.

```
y <- c(2448,2442,2438,2440,2438,2444,2431,2433,2434)
plot(y)

getFirstMin <- function(x){
  if(x[1] < x[2]) res <- 1
  else res <- min(which(diff(x) > 0))
  return(res)
}
getFirstMin(y)

z <- c(2408,2442,2438,2440,2438,2444,2431,2433,2434)
plot(z)
getFirstMin(z)
```

Comment: does `which.min(abs(diff(cummin(y))))` solve the problem?

Comment: so what should be the results from `z`?

Comment: what about `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`??

Comment: @onyambu taking the absolute value makes you flag the *smallest change* between consecutive values. Not OP's question, but coincidentally the right answer for this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `first`, `which`, `lag()` and `lead()`

```
getFirstMin<-function(x) {dplyr::first(which(lag(x, default = Inf) > x & lead(x, default = Inf) > x ) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier than @onyambu, a local minimum simply requires the first order difference is positive at some point, so with a nicely behaved sequence:

`y <- c(2448,2442,2438,2440,2438,2444,2431,2433,2434)`

`which(diff(y)>0)[1]`

gives 3. We could of course, build on this to handle some complicated cases, but your particular example demands nothing else.
[image]